# How to navigate by clicking on carousel image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. Currently I am working on owl carousel and I want to redirect to other page after clicking on carousel.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="col-xl-12">
        <h4>Movies</h4>
    </div>

    <div className="col-xl-12 ">
        <p className="font-weight-bold word_space">Most Popular</p>
    </div>

    <div className="col-xl-12">
        <OwlCarousel options={options}>

        <div>
            <img className="img_mp4"to="/main_page.jsx" src={Image} alt="img" />
        </div>

        <div>
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Help us help you by adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: basicall i want to redirect to next page ater clicking an image . have tried windows.location and link

Comment: @AKSHAYSALEKAR have your tried react-router?

Comment: @nutboltu i tried but i dont know how to apply it on image click. i saw some tutorials but they are telling me different stuff

Comment: You can use the Link component.

<Link to="/nextPage"><img src="your_image_src"/></Link>